# UITabBarControllerDelegate - methods not firing for delegate?

Tags: ios

i have a tabbarcontroller with 4 tabs. when the user selects one of the tabs i want to do some setup for the new view controller - i.e. ...[newVC.databaseid= self.datbaseid];

i have set the controller for he tabviewcontroller as it's delegate in viewdidload. however i have tried to use 3 methods, but only one seems to fire.

```
-(void) tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

DOES fire,

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

- DOES NOT seem to fire. this is the one i need to use to setup my newly presented VC.

just to see what happens, i tried using 
    - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

and that does not seem to fire either (i returned NO and it makes no difference, nor does anything get logged with NSLog();

if NONE of these methods fired i'd think i'd setup the delegate wrong, but one method does fire, but two don't. any ideas?

i have set the tabbarcontroller up using storyboards.

```
-(void) tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"item selected");
    //THIS DOES GET LOGGED
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"new VC");
    //this does not get logged
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
     return NO;
    //this doesnt stop any views being presented
}
```

Comment: i have found my issue - i was my fault.

i had done something stupid. i had setup the delegate with
self.tabbarcontroller.delegate = self

in the class that was the the controller for the tabbarcontroller

changing it to self.delegate = self;

has fixed the issue. quite a silly mistake!

strange how the first method was actually working though, but hey!

Comment: aIthough this was not the case, I think another common cause for the method not being called can be simply not attaching the controller in storyboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i have found my issue - i was my fault. i had done something stupid. i had setup the delegate with self.tabbarcontroller.delegate = self in the class that was the the controller for the tabbarcontroller changing it to self.delegate = self; has fixed the issue. quite a silly mistake! strange how the first method was actually working though, but hey!

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. This helped me :)

Comment: Yeah, it is weird. A UITabBarController subclass is not set as the default delegate of itself.